# How to make an array with array values?

Tags: php

I have some data that I need to organize so I could convert it to JSON. I get the data through a query which gives me the results. Some of the results are :

```
NAME - NUMBER, Direction, Color 
ABCD - 1, Left, Blue
ABCD - 2, Right, Red
ABCD - 3, Down, Green
EFGH - 1, UP, Yellow
EFGH - 2, Down, Orange
```

And I need to convert that data into something like this (so I could json_encode it):

```
$array = array({
  'name'=>'ABCD'
  [{ 'number'=>'1', 'direction'=>'left', 'color'=>'blue'} 
   { 'number'=>'2', 'direction'=>'right', 'color'=>'red' } 
   { 'number'=>'3', 'direction'=>'down', 'color'=>'green' }
  ]}
   { 'name'=>'EFGH'
  [{ 'number'=>'1', 'direction'=>'up', 'color'=>'yellow' } 
   { 'number'=>'2', 'direction'=>'down', 'color'=>'orange' }
  ]}
);
```

Not sure if it's correctly done, but I guess how the results should be.

Comment: Show us the code that queries the database please

Answer (score 0):

Generate a valid array and then `json_encode()` it:

```
<?php

$array = [
    'ABCD' => [
        ['number'=>'1', 'direction'=>'left', 'color'=>'green'],
        ['number'=>'2', 'direction'=>'right', 'color'=>'red'],
        ['number'=>'3', 'direction'=>'down', 'color'=>'green']
    ],
    'EFGH' => [
        ['number'=>'1', 'direction'=>'up', 'color'=>'yellow'],
        ['number'=>'2', 'direction'=>'down', 'color'=>'orange']
    ]
];

echo json_encode($array);
```

Access data by using something like `echo $array['EFGH'][0]['direction'];`

Comment: This is nice, but that is hardcoded. What if the values change with different queries? I need to do it as versatile as possible using variables where keys and values are ($result['name'] instead of 'ABCD' for example)

Comment: Then please post the code where you get your data and "convert" it to an array. Also post any errors you might get

Comment: I believe OP is asking for the code to convert it from the query to what you have here.

Comment: @Andreas Jupp, sounds like it

Comment: Yes, that's it. I will edit my message as soon as possible, but what I want is that, convert the results into an array which can be json_encode

Answer (score 0):

First generate an Array similar to the one you proposed. then json_encode it:

```
<?php
$data = array(
array("NAME" =>"ABCD", "NUMBER" => "1", "Direction" => "Left", "Color" => "Blue"),
array("NAME" =>"ABCD", "NUMBER" => "2", "Direction" => "Right", "Color" => "Red"),
array("NAME" =>"ABCD", "NUMBER" => "3", "Direction" => "Down", "Color" => "Green"),
array("NAME" =>"EFGH", "NUMBER" => "1", "Direction" => "UP", "Color" => "Yellow"),
array("NAME" =>"EFGH", "NUMBER" => "2", "Direction" => "Down", "Color" => "Orange")
);

$output = array();
foreach($data as $array) {
    $key = $array["NAME"];
    if(!isset($output[$key])) $output[$key] = array();
    $output[$key][] = $array;
}

//echo "<PRE>";
//print_r($output);
//echo "</PRE>";

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```